Nx operations hangs indefinitely
I'm trying to add Nx to my TS monorepo.
On first try, I installed it (pnpm i nx) but any run would hang on indefinitely. So I removed it, tried to reinstall it but now it hangs at postinstall
node_modules/.pnpm/nx@19.5.0_@swc+core@1.7.10/node_modules/nx: Running postinstall script

I tried other approach like pnpm dlx nx@latest init or even npx nx@latest init but it hangs at
 NX    Checking dependencies 

Also tried pnpm dlx create-nx-workspace from scratch but it hangs on the second step
Creating your workspace in test-nx

I tried multiple versions of Nx (from 19.5.0 to 19.5.7), multiple versions of PNPM and NPM. I cannot pinpoint what common operation hangs everytime. I removed node_modules, lock files, purge cache but nothing works and I'm out of solution.
Do you have any leads?
Env

Fedora 40
Node v20.11.1
Nx v19.5.0 to 19.5.7
PNPM v9.7.0
NPM v10.5.0


Did you try to run nx reset? It clears nx's cache and it might solve this issue

Didn't know this command. I crossed my fingers very hard, everything was cleaned but the error persists. Thank you for the idea
